# Xcode 15 - having issue while run on simulator but archive build successful

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm facing an issue with an 8-year-old Objective-C project where directly integrated three projects/frameworks into the codebase.

While I can successfully archive the build, running it on the simulator presents an error:
Library 'AFNetworking-library' not found
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

When I set EXCLUDED_ARCHS = arm64, it prompts "Executable Path is a Directory. xxx-xx.app is not a valid path to an executable file." Attempting to archive with this setting results in the error "lipo: no input files specified."

Setting VALID_ARCHS = x86_64 leads to the same error as above when running on the simulator:
Library 'AFNetworking-library' not found
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
However, archiving with the same settings is successful.

Seeking your guidance on this matter. Thank you!